# ¿Como logro correr mi aplicación en Docker con python?

Tags: python, docker

estoy haciendo mi trabajo de curso y necesito ayuda con mi versión de la aplicación que no me abre, está en Docker con python y cuando estoy instalándola para que corra, no me reconoce el comando virtualvenv desde el VScode, y cuando trato de instalarlo con (pip install virtualvenv),me pone esto(Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x046A86B0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10013] Intento de acceso a un socket no permitido por sus permisos de acceso',)': /simple/virtualvenv/
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement virtualvenv (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for virtualvenv), saludos y gracias de antemano.

Comment: Cómo usas Docker? Qué estás ejecutando? Podrías poner formato en el mensaje de error?

Comment: lo trato de ejecutar, pero no me corre porque me da error en el virtualenv, a la hora de poner las variables en el VSCode

Comment: Es una imagen existente? Tuviste que crearla con un dockerfile?

Comment: es un proyecto que está casi completo, a mi me tocó crear un apartado porque es una aplicación web, hecha con Docker y python, ya puse mis variables de entorno, instale python,pero a la hora de correr el dockerfile, me da error en el virtualenv

Comment: Podrias explicar un poco mejor? Pareciera que en algun lado estas intentando abrir un puerto de sistema, lo que suele requerir permisos de administrador. Pero solo pudo suponer, falta detalle en la pregunta.